# How to send amr file using bluetooth chat example

Tags: java, android

I am using bluetooth chat example, it's working properly. Now i'm trying to add extra feature to that. I recorded audio and that captured file is send to other bluetooth connected device.

Now i successfully capture audio saved in internal storage in amr file format.
i used used mediaRecorder for audio capture.

I don't have much knowledge on file input output streams. i'm facing problem at using bytestream for sending amr file.
If anyone know how to send amr file, help me.

Answer (score 0):

1)Save your amr file in a local path

2)Use that local path file (amr) to send data

3)Use below tutorial that use to transfer files (images here in sample) using gameKit

Hope it will help

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502

https://github.com/unixpickle/ImageTransfer